# TeXShop auto-save. Reversible?

Tags: texshop

So something pretty horrible just happened. I was editing my TeX, and I closed the TeX file and when I reopened the file, all my previous work was overwritten. The preview pdf from TeXshop remains, but everything else was overwritten by my scrap edits.

To further clarify, I still have the remaining .aux, .log, .out, .syntex.gz files

Is there any way to recover my previous work? And no, I didn't expect it would do that so I didn't have Time Machine.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329665/the-latex-file-coding-is-not-there-but-the-pdf-file-is-there/329708#329708

Comment: TeXShop uses Apple's Text Framework so inherits its features. Take a look at the `File->Revert To` menu item and see if that has what you want.