# tex file showing big size but no code when opened

Tags: packages

I was typing out my final year report when I hit compile and suddenly my whole computer shut down. When I booted it up and opened the 100kb tex file with TexStudio, the editor was completely empty and the pdf file says it was corrupted and the .synctex(busy). I have saved a backup from last month and the tex file is around 38kb so im sure my work is still mostly there but its showing nothing.

Someone please help

Comment: What gets shown if you open the `.tex` file with a plain text editor?

Comment: sadly this is not the first report of texstudio wiping files see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495542/thesis-turned-null  You should report it to the texworks developers if that is what has happened.

Comment: When opened with a plain text editor, it's just a whole bunch of random unicodes or whatever you call them. Just a bunch of nonsense. A friend of mine opened the file on his computer and it was just a whole text of blue @@@@@@@@@@@@@@ that filled the whole page

Comment: they are not random they will be ctrl-@ which is ascii 0, null.