# Help on how to recover the corrupted tex file as I'm unable to see any lines inside?

Tags: texstudio

It is really saddening to observe that my LaTex file got corrupted and the cause of it is unknown. I'm using Tex Studio as editor. The file size remaining big (say 150kb) but couldn't find any lines in that but columns do exist. I have dropped the zip file in overleaf to see if I could retrieve my .tex file but in vain.

I'm attaching the zip file in the following link if somebody could help me.

https://easyupload.io/6mhx9h

Looking forward to the stack exchange community for the continued help and service.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Against my better judgement, I downloaded your zip file. But you'll have to restore from backup. The file is just filled with null bytes.

Comment: You should report this to the texstudio developers it is not the first time I have seen that reported with that editor https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495542/thesis-turned-null

Comment: @DavidPurton: Thank you David.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you for the link. Is there any way to restore the file with any settings? as you said, I'll report to them.