# .tex file changed to full invalid characters after pc crash during running .tex file

Tags: compilation-error, texworks

so I was using TexWorks and while running my ut.tex code to create pdf , my pc suddenly crashed.
now ut.tex file has equal length to last version but it is all spaces (all in first line)

also if i try to run it again console output says:
Text line contains an invalid character.
*l.1 ^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^...*

note: i tried to use windows restore previous sessions but there were not any saved ones :(

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329708/2388

Comment: I have seen ths reported with other windows editors https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566305/help-on-how-to-recover-the-corrupted-tex-file-as-im-unable-to-see-any-lines-ins  `^^@` is ascii null, character 0, so your file has no data at all, and would need to be recovered from backup.