# suddenly, my .tex file stopped working, cannot copy .tex or .pdf file

Tags: errors

I was working on my file in TexStudio, and all of a sudden my .tex file stopped working. I cannot copy the folder in any other drive. .tex and ,pdf are the problem. also a file named `qt_temp.upBgti` appeared in the working folder.

When I want to copy it, this error pops up: `can't read from the source file or disk`.

I cannot make a zip file from it to upload on overleaf either. I can do nothing on the file.

I need to retrieve my .tex file and work on it ASAP.

Here is the last lines of the log if it can help:

```
Output written on Assignment_five.pdf (11 pages, 207724 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 252 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 80 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 197 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

revised: I ran a disk drive check and fix on that drive in Windows 10. What 
         happened is that now I can open the generated pdf, but the .tex file is 
         now totally empty. How can I retrieve what I had written in it?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a latex problem. It is probably something OS related. Or hardware malfunction.

Comment: @ Johannes_B but I can copy&paste other pdf files within the same drive. I can run other .tex files in the same drive in texStudio

Comment: Use a task manager and check if latex is still running somehow or if any other process keeps the file open.

Comment: @ Johannes_B I already checked it, but it is not the case.

Comment: Can you open a simple text editor like notepad and copy/save your text there? That way, at least the text is safe.

Comment: @  Johannes_B I ran a disk drive check and fix on that drive in Windows 10. What happened is that now I can open the generated pdf, but the .tex file is now totally empty. How can I retrieve what I had written in it?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329708/2388