# Is there any way to recover the text file or at least the PDF file from corrupt text file in LaTeX?

Tags: texstudio

I was using TeXstudio but suddenly due to a problem with my computer, my `.tex` file got corrupted.

The PDF output is not opening as well, though it shows 21 kb size data.

In the folder, I saw 4 types of extension files besides the `.tex` file:

1. `.aux` file,
2. `.out` file,
3. `.pdf` file,
4. `.log` file.

Is there any way to recover the text file or at least the PDF file?

Comment: Just restore from your backup.  You have a backup, right?

Comment: @HenriMenke, how to restore the backup? can you help me ? i have less knowledge in this

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329708/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Is there automatic ~.bak~ file in Text studio editor? How to find it ?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use texstudio.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR I don't know what your backup plan is.  I have my backups stored on an external hard drive and on my personal server.

Comment: @HenriMenke, ok got it.Unfortunately I didn't store in extra place (e.g.pendrive).