# Text line error

Tags: auxiliary-files

My tex file (chapter2 in particular) crashed and somehow the tex file is not compilable anymore! The affected chapter2 in the tex file won't even display any code, it's blank, it's showing some pink and sometimes blue colors if I tried to copy. Actually, this happened after I copied a few lines from a PDF document. I tried deleting the .aux file but TexStudio cannot compile it anymore.

I get serious errors, but other chapters and other files seem to be OK. Any clue?

Log-file chunk:

```
*\openout2 = `chapter2.aux'.
 (chapter2.tex
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1  
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1   
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1    
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1     
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1      
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1       
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1        
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1         
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1          
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1           
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1            
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1             
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1              
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1               
                                                                          ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1 ...                                           
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1 ...                                           
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1 ...                                           
                                                                            ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1 ...                                           
                                                                            ...
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13554 strings out of 493308
 199066 string characters out of 3138772
 349512 words of memory out of 3000000
 16839 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 10112 words of font info for 23 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 48i,6n,43p,77726b,410s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!*
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Such a problem is almost never the result of a LaTeX compilation, rather some system or editor problem.  This question describes a similar problem, and the answers may help you figure out what happened: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329665  I hope you have a backup.

Comment: Thanks, @Barbara Beeton, very unfortunate I don't have a backup. I have gone through the answers to the question but nothing yet.

Comment: This happened to me in LyX just now. I closed LyX and re-opened it and I was able to compile again!