# Miktex file is empty

Tags: miktex

I use `Miktex` editor to write `latex` code. It suddenly gives me the error about it cannot save file and ask whether I want to save a copy. Unfortunately, I did not save a copy close the editor and try to reopen the file, it is empty. I tried to restart the computer but nothing was changed. I tried to find a file with disk drill but it has hex and special character and it is not the format that could be human readable. I also check the temp file I find some files that save log of tex compile and not the tex file content. What should I do?

Comment: well what you should *not* have done it to restart the computer. Never do anything if you lost a file but first try to save whatever you can find. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329708/2388. Beside this: recovering files is not really on topic here.

Comment: I think it is because of low disk space and I don't know what I should do. any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask. You lost a file and that is not a latex problem, but a computer problem.

Comment: No, it is a miktex editor problem.

Comment: Then try to open the file in some other editor.